# composer updating kriswallsmith/assetic

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I have a problem when updating the vendor   "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*", the update gives me this output :

```
 Updating kriswallsmith/assetic (dev-master 5591252 => v1.1.2)

 [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                
  The .git directory is missing from /home/smiles/Downloads/auth_Project/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic, see http://getcomposer.org/commit-deps for more information
```

Answer (score 0):

This literally means what it says: the .git directory is missing from this vendor directory. Simply remove the whole assetic folder, then run `composer update` again. This will add assetic again and the .git folder. (If the `kriswallsmith` `vendor namespace` is empty, then you are safe to remove that empty folder as well.)

This can happen if - for example - you are using subversion and all .git folders are ignored. Upon next checkout this folder will not be present.